# Regarding Dynamic Routing in Veins

Tags: veins

In the example given in Veins' example scenario in Erlangen city when the accident occurs do other vehicle choose a different path after for the duration of the accident?
If yes, how does this dynamic routing take place???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, vehicles take other routes due to the accident to avoid the following traffic jam. That is the whole point of informing other vehicles about the accident using IVC here.

Regarding rerouting see [TraCIDemo11p.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L48) (l. 48) and [TraCICommandInterface.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc#L138) (l. 138).

Edit: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372048/what-exactly-does-handleparkingupdate-do/43430215#43430215) for more information.