# VEINS: Dynamic re-routing algorithm

Tags: routes, simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

In SUMO, while converting OSM file to SUMO compatible road network using DUAROUTER we can pass --routing.algorithm parameter to use one of [these](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Routing#Routing_Algorithms) (default is Dijkstra).

In veins demo app there is a logic to simulate accident and vehicles reroute on receiving warning message. I'm trying to understand how rerouting is working there. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781147/regarding-dynamic-routing-in-veins) post says re-routing is dynamic and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373278/what-policy-is-based-vehicle-rerouting-in-case-of-accident) is some more explanation of the scenario.

My question is while rerouting which routing algorithm veins uses? Is it the same using which road network is created? If I have to chechk behavior of different routing algorithms under same conditions, do I need to create same road network using different values for --routing.algorithm ?

Comment: According to http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Routing the same parameter can be set for the sumo or sumo-gui binary as well to influence which routing algorithm gets used. Have you tried that out?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I didn't tried passing same parameter to SUMO or SUMO-GUI yet, will definitely give that a try. But still I need clarification regarding first part of my question i.e. let say if I start sumo server using `/c/veins-veins-4.6/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c '/c/sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe --routing.algorithm astar'` then VEINS will use astar to find alternate routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question at the end is yes.

As far as I know, the routing you're referring to is all in SUMO, which is the *default* used by VEINS. As soon as you make changes to the routing behavior at run time, VEINS essentially takes over and tells SUMO how to route its vehicles. What this means for your project is that you either implement the routing completely in advance (i.e., independent of the code in VEINS) in SUMO, or you implement some re-routing algorithm that is completely in VEINS. SUMO can't do dynamic re-routing based on application knowledge, because SUMO isn't aware of this information, since SUMO is built independent of any vehicular communication system.